# How can I do this Scala SQL (Slick 1.0.1) query in a functional rather than mutable manner?

Tags: sql, scala, slick

I have a Scala Slick table of School objects and I want to filter based upon 0-5 parameters contained within a filter object `SchoolFilter`:

```
case class SchoolFilter(name: Option[String], 
                        city: Option[String], 
                        state: Option[String],
                        zip: Option[String], 
                        district: Option[String])
```

A `None` value means "don't filter on this key at all" because I have a html page with a table of School objects and an AJAX call that does a filter based upon user input. I implemented this behaviour by creating a mutable list of all schools and then running a filter on each member of `SchoolFilter` that is defined. But the method doesn't seem horribly efficient, sucking in all of the records from the database and then making (potentially) 5 passes over the list before returning the results.

Is there a more functional (or perhaps more efficient) way of accomplishing this goal?

```
def findSchoolsByFilter(f: SchoolFilter = SchoolFilter(None, None, None, None, None), 
                        n: Int = 5)
                       (implicit session: Session) = Try {
  var s = collection.mutable.LinkedList(Query(Schools).list().toSeq: _*)
  if (f.name.isDefined)
    s = s.filter(_.name.toLowerCase.startsWith(f.name.get.toLowerCase))
  if (f.city.isDefined)
    s = s.filter(_.city.toLowerCase.startsWith(f.city.get.toLowerCase))
  if (f.state.isDefined)
    s = s.filter(_.state.toLowerCase.startsWith(f.state.get.toLowerCase))
  if (f.zip.isDefined)
    s = s.filter(_.zip.toLowerCase.startsWith(f.zip.get.toLowerCase))
  if (f.district.isDefined)
    s = s.filter(_.district.toLowerCase.startsWith(f.district.get.toLowerCase))
  List(s.toSeq: _*).take(n).sorted
}
```

Comment: My guess is reducing a `Seq[SchoolFilter => Option[String]]`.

Comment: Though I wouldn’t worry as much about the mutable list as about the duplicate code. Use higher-order functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Local mutability (contained within a function, no leaked) is usually not a problem. Mutability becomes hard, when you have to reason about several places in your code modifying the same thing. But you can improve readability and efficiency of your code using a functional style. We can do the filter as a completely lazy query builder. No database round-trip, just building of an appropriate query, which means also no session needed anymore for your function.

```
def findSchoolsByFilter(f: SchoolFilter = SchoolFilter(None, None, None, None, None), 
                        n: Int = 5) = {
  /** Case insensitive option startsWith */
  def iStartsWith( a:Column[String], bOption:Option[String] ) = bOption.map( b => a.toLowerCase startsWith b.toLowerCase )

  Query(Schools).filter( s =>
    Seq(
      iStartsWith( s.name, f.name ),
      iStartsWith( s.city, f.city ),
      iStartsWith( s.state, f.state ),
      iStartsWith( s.zip, f.zip ),
      iStartsWith( s.district, f.district )
    ).flatten.reduce(_ && _) // flatten removes Nones and unwrap the Somes XMAS-Style
  ).take(n)
}
```

You could even go one step further and make schools an argument to findSchoolsByFilter, so you can lazily combine this filter with other filters.